# KOTLIN orphanRemoval not working

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

Is any one having the similar issue of removing child records but fail to use orphanRemoval annotation ?

Below is my code sample in Model Class constructor:

```
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL))
@JoinColumn(name = "categoryId", nullable = false)
var books: List<BOOK> = emptyList()
```

The CRUD with the ***cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL)*** is work perfectly, but when adding ***orphanRemoval = true*** into "ONE-TO-MANY" annotation, it could not work any more and throw the exception as below:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with
>   cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning
>   entity instance:

the purpose of adding orphanRemoval to remove the child record permanently from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@OneToMany(cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL), orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "categoryId", nullable = false)
var books: MutableList<BOOK> = mutableListOf()
    set(value) {
        field.clear()
        field.addAll(value)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a blog post that explains what might be the cause of such exception: http://www.onkarjoshi.com/blog/188/hibernateexception-a-collection-with-cascade-all-delete-orphan-was-no-longer-referenced-by-the-owning-entity-instance/

> You are setting a new collection via the setter thus leaving the original collection unreferenced by the Parent entity. This doesn’t fly well with Hibernate and leaves it confused about what to do.

`books` is `var`, not `val` so I assume that in some place in your code, you are setting it to the desired value. Assuming the reasoning from the blog post is valid here, using `final` field of mutable type should be way to go,

```
val books: MutableList<BOOK> = mutableListOf()
```